# event.stopPropagation stops propagation of live events, although it should not

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, live

The documentation for says that event.stopPropagation shouldn't stop propagation of live events (http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation). However it works just the opposite for me. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/PSYg8. Clicking on the red Div should fire the live event attached to the html element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the documentation is telling you is that it is not possible to call `stopPropagation` *from* a `live` handler.

Because jQuery implements `live` events by listening to all events that propagate up to the `<html>` element and then seeing if the firing element matches your original selector, stopping propagation from a regular event handler on an element prevents the event from ever reaching the `live` handler.

**Edit:** If you're not clear on how DOM events and event propagation works, [QuirksMode has a wonderful analysis of the capturing and bubbling models](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html), and Microsoft has a [great page that lets you visualize how event propagation works](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/ComparingEventModels/Default.html) in the W3C, classic, and IE models.

Comment: Oh, my bad.. But is there anyway to do what I want to do, ie, be sure that one event handler gets called when the user clicks anywhere on a page and no matter what's in the way? It's for a popover. So I want to catch all clicks on the page and if the target of them doesn't have popover as a parent then i close the popover.

Comment: There's no way to guarantee that a bubbling event's propagation won't be stopped.  Even if *you* never call `e.stopPropagation()`, you might be using a jQuery plugin that does.  You could step outside of jQuery's event mechanisms *(bad idea!)* and register a handler in the [caputuring phase](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html), but that isn't even possible in IE < 9.  Your best bet in this situation is to add an overlay `<div>` above the page content and directly below the popup.  Register a simple `click` handler on the `<div>` and hide from there.

Comment: Alternatively, save yourself from reinventing the wheel and use something like [UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal) or [SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/).

Answer (score 0):

You're swapping the items. Inside `.live`, you cannot use `stopPropagation`. So for example this does generate two alerts: http://jsfiddle.net/PSYg8/1/.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('html').live('click', function(){
        alert('html');
        event.stopPropagation();
    });

    $('div').click(function(event){
        alert('div');
    });
});
```

Inside `.click` (`.bind`), `stopPropagation` works seamlessly. It just stops the div event from bubbling up to the html element.

Answer (score 0):

> Since the .live() method handles events once they have propagated to the top of the document, it is not possible to stop propagation of live events

Meaning

```
$('html').live('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation(); // does nothing
    alert('html');
});
```

You misinterpreted the documentation. When you stop propagation on the click event it does not bubble upto the live event.